# Why is the Msgbox acting weirdly?

Tags: vb.net

Here is button code :

```
Dim ha as integer =0
Private Sub Button13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    ha = ha + 1
    If ha < 3 Then
        *Msgbox("Hint(s) taken = " & ha)
        hint = hint - 5
    Else
        MsgBox("You cant Take More HINTS :P")
    End If

End Sub
```

Now the problem is that the * msgbox keeps on appearing infinite times
The value of ha shown is always 1.....weird
If i remove that line then the code works fine!!
why is this happening?
What should i do to get rid of this!!

Comment: Are you initializing the variable ha at any other place before the button click?

Comment: Is this winforms, where do you initialize `ha` where is this form created?

Comment: I m intializing 'ha' at beginning of the the class
Anyway ha doesnt matter.......even though i replace it with any other msgbox like : msgbox"HI"
Still it keeps on appearing

Comment: Clearify your question

Comment: What you mean `ha` doesn't matter? Its all that matters, `ha` is exactly what determines which MsgBox will throw.

Comment: The thing is that......wen i click on the button it keeps on printing "Hints taken =1"......if i remove that msgbox then the code works fine

Comment: Debug and see what `ha` is on each button click. BTW `msgbox` is not best practice, use `MessageBox.show()`

Comment: code should work . which net framework you are using . or post entire code if it is small

Comment: Run this in debug and see the call stack after the messagebox is shown. My guess, you are double clicking on the OK button of the messagebox and button3 is behind it, as a result - click is getting executed. In any case, it should not appear more than 3 times because of the condition check. Also, add `option explicit` at the top.

Comment: There is no simple explanation for this.  Set a breakpoint on the MsgBox statement.  The second time it hits, copy/paste the Debug + Windows + Call Stack window content into your question.